# Unwanted indentation in optimization problem using aligned environment

Tags: math-mode, aligned

I want to type the following optimization problem into latex.
[image]

I want g_0 to be aligned with J_obj and 1/2 with +. If I try a similar example with placeholders everything works fine, however if I put in my equations the first line gets indented from the 1/2 on as shown here:
[image]

I came up with this code which I think should work but obviously it doesn't, help would be highly appreciated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \min_{\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_{\mathrm{d}}} \quad &g_0\left(\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_{\mathrm{d}}\right) = 
    &~\frac{1}{2}\left(\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_{\mathrm{d}}-\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}^{\prime}_{\mathrm{trp}}\right)^{\mathrm{T}} \boldsymbol{W}_{\mathrm{1}} \left(\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_{\mathrm{d}}-\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}^{\prime}_{\mathrm{trp}}\right)\\
    & &+\sum_{j=1}^{N_{\mathrm{J}}}\sum_{l=1}^{N_{\mathrm{obs}}}\frac{1}{2}\left(\boldsymbol{v}_{j\mathrm{,d}}-\boldsymbol{v}_{j\mathrm{,obs,}l}\right)^{\mathrm{T}} \boldsymbol{W}_{\mathrm{3,}jl} \left(\boldsymbol{v}_{j\mathrm{,d,}j}-\boldsymbol{v}_{j\mathrm{,obs,}l}\right)\\
     \textrm{s.t.} \quad &\boldsymbol{J}_{\mathrm{obj}}
\end{aligned}    
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use only 1 instance of `&` per row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{bm} % '\bm' is shorter than '\boldsymbol'
% 2 handy shortcut macros:
\newcommand\qd{\Dot{\bm{q}}_{\mathrm{d}}}     % occurs 4 times
\newcommand\qtrp{\Dot{\bm{q}}_{\mathrm{trp}}} % occurs twice

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{\qd} g_0(\qd) 
&= \frac{1}{2}(\qd-\qtrp')^{\mathrm{T}} \bm{W}_{1} (\qd -\qtrp') \\
&\quad+\sum_{j=1}^{N_{\mathrm{J}}}
       \sum_{l=1}^{N_{\mathrm{obs}}}
  \frac{1}{2}
  (\bm{v}_{j,\mathrm{d}} -\bm{v}_{j,\mathrm{obs},l})
  ^{\mathrm{T}} \bm{W}_{3,jl} 
  (\bm{v}_{j,\mathrm{d},j}-\bm{v}_{j,\mathrm{obs},l}) \\
\text{s.t. }\bm{J}_{\mathrm{obj}} \cdot \qd 
&= \Dot{\bm{x}}_{\mathrm{obj},d}\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}} 
% use '\vphantom' to balance row heights (matters for placement of eq. no.)
\end{aligned}    
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Also nice of you to show me the best practice with defining newcommands :)

Comment: @Rememberless - You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You could write the first two lines in their own `aligned` environment. This way you can control the alignment of the `g_0` and `J_{obj}` independently of the alignement of the ½ and the +.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \min_{\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_{\mathrm{d}}} \quad &g_0\left(\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_{\mathrm{d}}\right) = 
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        & \frac{1}{2}\left(\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_{\mathrm{d}}-\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}^{\prime}_{\mathrm{trp}}\right)^{\mathrm{T}} \boldsymbol{W}_{\mathrm{1}} \left(\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}_{\mathrm{d}}-\Dot{\boldsymbol{q}}^{\prime}_{\mathrm{trp}}\right)\\
        & +\sum_{j=1}^{N_{\mathrm{J}}}\sum_{l=1}^{N_{\mathrm{obs}}}\frac{1}{2}\left(\boldsymbol{v}_{j\mathrm{,d}}-\boldsymbol{v}_{j\mathrm{,obs,}l}\right)^{\mathrm{T}} \boldsymbol{W}_{\mathrm{3,}jl} \left(\boldsymbol{v}_{j\mathrm{,d,}j}-\boldsymbol{v}_{j\mathrm{,obs,}l}\right)
    \end{aligned} \\
    \textrm{s.t.} \quad &\boldsymbol{J}_{\mathrm{obj}}
\end{aligned}    
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for :)